# Can't login to two laravel project in same browser another log out

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.5

I am working on the Laravel project 5.3 and the problem I am facing is when I log in to frontend or the admin Panel another session destroy and logouts the application, need some solution. Both are running on different ports like

1. example.com
2. example.com:75/public
3. example.com:81/public

I am extremely sorry for the bad English and thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check if the `session` configuration is different? ([see `session.cookie`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L125))

Answer (score 5):

User session is stored in the browser cookie, and cookie is related to website domain name. So in your case looks like you use one cookie file for two websites (because it use same name). You can configure virtual host to solve this.

Comment: I guess the solution is to redirect them two different domain name

Comment: I solved this by changing the name of the project in .env as by default the cookie name is the projectname_session.

Answer (score 4):

I just changed my .env configuration:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file

CACHE_PREFIX=*with_different_name*

SESSION_DRIVER=file

SESSION_COOKIE=*with_different_name_session*
```

change chache_prefix and session_cookie with different name between your project

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect one of them something like `project.local` and connect the other with `localhost:8000` 
Just search `laravel vhost(virtual host)`. Thats easy. Good Luck.

Comment: there are more than 30 users who are working on the application so this is not the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Actually we are working like that. All workers using own system. something like project.local and everybody has own ip. Cookies are saving for  everybodies own browser.
For example public connection is 192.168.2.2XX
Everybody has own XX.

Comment: Actually, we are not working together they are at different places. I got the solution we will be having the different domain name for different pots and it will solve my problem Thank you for your valuable time